# How to treat predictor time series when their length is smaller than the value to be forecasted and it is not possible to increase it?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python

I want to use EUR/USD historical data as a predictor for stock return in my Machine Learning project. But I have data for the stock since 1986. At the same time, the data for the currency pair is from around the time the Euro was introduced as a currency - 1999.
I would like to know how to deal with this missing data since it is obviously impossible to "invent" it on my own.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated. Your forecast relies on modeling the relationship between EUR and USD. Yes, before 1999 there are no recordings for the Euro, because it didn't exist then - based on this, what do you think the relationship between EUR and USD was like ? It's akin to asking how a person got along with their parents before their conception.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a statistical question that has an economics answer.

The Euro is the successor to the [European Currency Unit (ECU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Currency_Unit), which was a bundle of currencies used as an electronic unit of account. The Euro replaced the ECU on 1 January 1999 at a value of 1 EUR = 1 ECU. The Wikipedia page contains [a table with the weights of the constituent currencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Currency_Unit#Value_determined_by_basket_of_currencies), which changed over time.

So my recommendation would be to extend your USD/EUR rate with a USD/ECU rate, which wou would determine as a weighted combination of USD/BEF, USD/DEM etc. rates, with weights given in that table.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of some currency basket but didn't think of the ECU. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. If my post answered your question, please consider *accepting* it, by clicking the small checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very useful [dataset](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/EXUSEC?cid=280).
It is from the Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis and has the missing values I was looking for but on a monthly basis.